# mpg123 plays only 10 songs then quits

Tags: bash, sorting, random, tail

```
#/bin/bash
ls |sort -R |tail -$N |while read file; do
mpg123 "$file" 
sleep 3
done
```

any idea why it only plays 10 mp3's and exits?
There are hundreds of mp3's in the same directory as this file (playmusic.sh)

Thanks

Comment: so can I completely omit $N?

Comment: 10 lines is the default output count for head & tail. if $N isn't defined at all, then this code would become `tail -`, telling tail to read from stdin, which would be `sort`'s output.... and you'd end up with only 10 lines (filenames) being passed on to be played

Comment: I simply omitted the tail part :   
#/bin/bash
    cd ~/Music/all
    ls ~/Music/all |sort -R |while read file; dompg123 "$file"
    sleep 3
done

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B said the problem occurs due to the variable N not being set which leads `tail` to default to its default number of lines which is 10. (Obviously it can also occur if N is actually set to 10.)

The fundamental problem here is you didn't understand what this code actually does. I suspect you didn't actually write this code yourself. Even though it's a bash script, it expects a variable N to be set. This is highly unorthodox for a bash script, you would normally use

```
$1
```

instead of `$N`, or better still

```
${1:?}
```

which would display an error and exit immediately, if you forgot to pass in a command-line argument.